# How to map reads shorter than 32bp with minimap2?

Tags: fasta, read-mapping, phylogenetics, bwa, minimap2

I mapped fasta sequences to a reference. The fasta sequences range in length from 17bp up to several hundred bp. I used `minimap2` with the following command: `minimap2 -ax sr ref.fa seqs.fa`, et cetera. Only the sequences greater than 32bp len mapped though.

```
samtools view -F 4 filename.sorted.bam | \
  cut -f10 | awk '{print length($1)}' | \
  sort | uniq -c | sort -k2 -n

   2304 32
  34931 33
   5443 34
   5343 35
   8811 36
   5485 37
   5417 38
```

Is it possible to make minimap2 map sequences shorter than 32bp? Do I need to use `bwa aln` or some other mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimap2 is not the most optimal aligner in this case, it was designed for long reads, of which 32bp reads are clearly not. You could try lowering the  mnimizer k-mer length and with `-k` the default being 15, also try lowering the minimzer window size with `-w`.  However I suggest using `bwa aln` and `bwa samse` for all reads under 32bp and then merging the alignment later. Although I struggle to see what the utility of these short reads will be against a backdrop of longer reads?

Comment: They aren't really reads per se - just short sequences from another application that I need to align. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Minimap2 doesn't work well with 32bp reads by design. Older mappers like bowtie1 and bwa-aln will be better.